# What is the purpose of the negative score badges?

Tags: discussion, voting, badges

There are (at least) two badges, which are related to a negative score.

> **Reversal:** Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score
>
> **Peer Pressure:** Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower

I've read comments like this several times:

> Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in it's current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. (by Henri Menke on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150006/changing-to-a-vertical-table-in-latex#comment341490_150006)

I've even read a comment like this on a question which clearly stated that: "How to do that? I'm lazy and don't want to look for a solution." - The comment got upvoted and downvoting stopped at -2 (-3 actually, but someone gave an upvote (I don't know why)). The question was finally closed as a duplicate (as far as I can remember).

These comments usually get upvoted quickly, so I think that these two badges are outdated here. I suppose we don't want anyone to be motivated to downvote anything to make a Reversal badge possible.

---

**Questions:**

Are they outdated here Are the badges the same on all SE sites? Shouldn't they be switched off (moved to inactive state)? Or: is the idea of not voting below -1 contradicting with original SE intentions?

(Should this question be tagged as [support] because "I need help with the use of one of the site's features"?)

---

**About answering downvoted questions:**

Should we answer questions which are downvoted / low quality?

Comment: Since Badges are universal for all SE sites, you’re unlikely to achieve a different solution only for tex.sx. I would agree that the idea of not voting below -1 contradicts the SE intentions – otherwise it wouldn’t  even be _possible_. I’m not a fan of that policy, but I haven’t found the time to check up on previous discussions on meta and potentially start a new one, so I stick to it most of the time. It’s just that many terrible questions end up with a positive score because not every (apparently strangely-reasoned) upvote is countered with another downvote to go back to -1.

Comment: As the owner of one of the three Reversal badges I long for the days when vicious downvoting was the norm. :) No, such downvoting has never been the norm, and I think that the site is better off for it, honestly. Downvoting and close voting seem to attract a kind of 'piling on' behaviour which I find troubling. Maybe the SE network wants to be that way, but I think many of us have decided that we don't.  If that means that the number of reversal badges will stay at 3, then so be it.

Comment: Notice also that the Reversal badge rewards a positive contribution but the Peer Pressure badge is a kind of incentive against posting crappy answers.

Comment: The norm here is different from other SE sites, and the same goes for badge earnings. Consider, for the example, the (virtually unattainable) [Tenacious silver badge](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/tenacious) and [Unsung hero gold badge](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero). They fall under the same category relating to votes/score - zero that is.

Comment: For the EDIT `question`: Related [Should we answer really bad questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414/15717)

Comment: I wasn't sure if the badges are the some or was originally copied and not modified. I think the purpose of the badges can only be motivational/rewarding. I'm glad to see this unison about the badge system and the downvoting. I think the same about both of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I try to keep it at negative one because negative answers are not assesed for being good. Hence it doesn't even make sense to compare a -5 voted q/a with a -1 voted q/a

A negative number is enough to draw attention that it is a crappy q/a and makes a point. -17 doesn't always mean the question is wrong. Sometimes the attitude rubs people the wrong way and downvotes pile up.

If this blocks a few badges on the way, fine so be it. What do you need them badges for in the first place?

And yes I'm not a fan of following SO rules that are designed for a Q/A site with  hundred questions per hour on a site that is way too cozy than SO.

Comment: "*What do you need them badges for in the first place?*"... I wanted to print them to pin it onto my chest. :) No, I don't really see the point of the badge system, but I think its original intention is to be a(n) reward/achievement. So it has a motivational purpose (for some), therefore it shouldn't motivate anyone to do things which confronts the community standards.

Comment: @SándorKazi I suggest a tattoo instead :P

Comment: @percusse If someone actually got "Reversal" and "Peer Pressure" tattooed unto their chest in TeX.SX style, I would tattoo their name in a big pink heart on myself.

Comment: @NictraSavios I would recommend looking at the user names on the main site. That's a dangerous game :P

Answer (score 8):

Ratio of **[Peer Pressure]/[Nice Answer]** awarded badges (I take Nice Answer as a measure of the size of the site):

- StackOverflow (the largest site): **10%**
- Mathematics.SE (significantly large site): **4%**
- TeX.SE (our site): **0.08%**
- Academia.SE (small site still in beta): **2%**

Conclusions:

- We are one of the few sites that doesn't really downvote bad questions (well, we knew that before this my little survey, right?)
- Therefore we are one of the few sites where Peer Pressure and Reversal badges are ridiculous
- We should just don't care about these badges too much.

Last comment:

- Don't care too much about the measures: rep points and badges. They are fine, they are fun, but much more important is to make a good and positive contribution, and this is very hard to measure, one has to feel it :)